# How can I apply 'offset' to an element inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to navigate to a div inside an iframe using `jQuery.animate` from a link outside the iframe. 
This is the Code I use:

```
function scrollToAnchorIframe(aid){
  var aTag = window.frames['myFrame'].document.getElementById(aid);
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top - 62},'slow');
}
```

However, it doesn't work, logging the error "`Object [object HTMLElement] has no method 'offset'`". Is there a way to get the offset of the id to make it work?

Update (Solved): 
That's the code I'm using now:

```
function scrollToAnchorIframe(aid){
  var aTag = window.frames['myFrame'].document.getElementById(aid);
  jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(aTag).offset().top + $("#myFrame").offset().top - 62},'slow');
}
```

Comment: You're getting that error because the object isn't a jQuery object. It's an HTMLElement. Try `$(aTag).offset()` or wrap the `window.frames['myFrame'].document.getElementById(aid);` in a `$()`

Comment: Note that you cannot use X-Frame programming unless you work on same domain with same protocol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aTag` is DOM element , make it jQuery object

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(aTag).offset().top - 62},'slow');
```

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick. Here is the complete code I use now:     `function scrollToAnchorIframe(aid){
      var aTag = window.frames['myFrame'].document.getElementById(aid);
      jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(aTag).offset().top + $("#myFrame").offset().top - 62},'slow');
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If the iframe is put inside a container box, here's an update in order to navigate up/down to the iframe's bookmark-anchor from the parent-page container (note: "window.frames" has a known compatibility bug with FF browser, so i'll use "contentWindow" instead):

```
function iframeBookmark(anchor) {
mytag = document.getElementById("iframeID").contentWindow.document.getElementById(anchor);
pos1 = $(mytag).offset().top;
pos2 = $("#iframeID").offset().top;
if (pos2 > pos1) {
    $("#iframeContainerID").animate({scrollTop: pos2 - (pos2 - pos1) },'slow');
    }
else {
    $("#iframeContainerID").animate({scrollTop: pos2 + (pos1 - pos2)  },'slow');
    }
}
```

So, when we call the function from the parent HTML, the up/down scroll depends to the iframe current position:

```
 <a onclick="iframeBookmark('iframeBookmarkID')">...</a>
```

...where 'iframeBookmarkID' is the ID of the bookmark-anchor in the iframe page.